# Flash XML whitespace problem

Tags: xml, flash, whitespace, removing-whitespace

How can I have Flash reading XML ignore white spaces that would be ignored in HTML?

```
<![CDATA[
   Some text here.
   More text here.             ]]>
```

I don't want the spaces or the new lines that show in the text to show in Flash. In HTML there is no new line character between the two lines either.

Is that possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add your text to a textField you need to use the condenseWhite property. condenseWhite only works on htmlText. So do something like:

```
txt.condenseWhite = true;
txt.htmlText = myXML.myNode[0];
```

I remember at some point a few years ago I had a program where I wasn't using htmlText and it took me ages to figure out that condenseWhite doesn't work with the regular old text property, so remember this only works with htmlText. Hope this helps.

Comment: It does, Zevan. Thank you very much.